# Image Enhancement by adding 2 images in Octave

Tags: image-processing, octave

[image]

Hello!

I would like to process an image like all steps in this picture in Octave.
I wonder how I can add to images together to get a picture like (c) of (f)?
My code so far is:

```
I = imread('343a.tif');
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(I);title('Original Image'); 
I = im2double (I);
H = fspecial('log', 11,1.5);
Laplacian = imfilter(I,H,'replicate');
subplot(2,2,2);imshow(Laplacian, []);title('Laplacian Image');
H = fspecial('sobel');
Edge = imfilter(I,H,'replicate');
subplot(2,2,4);imshow(Edge);title('Sobel Image');
```

Would be very thankful for help or suggestions! :)

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add images using the `+` operator and multiply them using the `.*` operator:

```
c = a + b;
f = c .* e;
```

Yes, it's really that simple! :)